# Cordova: open link from webview in target blank without plugin

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a simple cordova app with this is my config.xml:

> < content src="http://example.com" />

In other words, the app simply loads an website.
The problem is that this website has some hrefs with target="_blank" but the webview doesn't open the default browser when the link is clicked/tapped; the link is loaded inside the webview.
I know that there's the InAppBrowser plugin, but i think I cannot use it with this approach (the hosted webpage would not load the plugin).
Does anyone know how to deal with this? Any recommendation?

Comment: my recommendation is not to load an external site changing the content src, that is for development phase only, you shouldn't create phonegap apps that just load websites. Now, answering your question, as you can't use plugins, you can't open the website on the external browser, the only way is to change the cordova source code on the webview load methods to open some links in the external browser

Comment: @jcesarmobile I really know this (what I'm trying to do) is not the best approach. The thing is that I'm developing a personal project and I don't have enough spare time to build another frontend for the app right know (the website is written in Rails). I have plans to do a "real" app in the future, I was just figuring out if there was any chance to do that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: then change the code on shouldStartLoadWithRequest (iOS) and shouldOverrideUrlLoading (android) to open some urls on the browser. You can check the inAppBrowser plugin code to see how to open a browser.